# Панель YUI становится прозрачной на сервере

Tags: javascript, дизайн, css

Панель YUI становится прозрачной, когда загружаю на сервер, а на локалхосте без проблем - серенькая.

В чем может быть причина и возможные способы лечения?  (YUI библиотеки пробовал подключать и к внешним библиотекам на яху, и к загруженным на хостинг.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все, нашел причину. Дело в ЮМИ!